# R- Match a Cell to another to retrieve a value for a different row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table of data where each value for the Filename column has a set of values in the Compound column. Some of the Compound values have an IS value that matches another Compound. I need to match the value in IS to the Compound column, retrieve the value for Chrom.1.RT from that row, then put that value in the IS_RT column on the row where the IS value was.

Example:

```
Filename    Compound    Chrom.1.RT  IS  IS_RT

1_04        Amp_d6      2.93075     0   0
1_04        Bup_d4      7.280333    0   0
1_04        Cocaine_d3  5.66195     0   0
1_04        10-monohyd  0           Cocaine_d3  5.66195
1_04        2-hydroxy   0           Bup_d4  0
1_04        6-MAM       3.566433    Amp_d6  0
1_05        Amp_d6      2.94        0   0
1_05        Bup_d4      7.3         0   0
1_05        Cocaine_d3  5.65        0   0
1_05        10-monohyd  0           Cocaine_d3  5.65
1_05        2-hydroxy   0           Bup_d4  0
1_05        6-MAM       3.6         Amp_d6  0
```

The lines for 10-monohyd show what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure where to start with this. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

Here's code that I've tried, doesn't seem to work:

```
sampleList <- unique(df1$Filename)

for (i in sampleList){
  SampleRows<-which(df1$Filename == sampleList[i])
  RefRows <- subset(df1, Filename== sampleList[i])
  df1$IS.RT[SampleRows]<- RefRows$Chrom.1.RT[match(df1$IS[SampleRows], RefRows$Compound)]
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing the first step would be to actually split this into groups based on the `Filename` record after looking at this again... see answer below for a push in the right direction hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I'm not too confident I understood your question, but here's what I got based on my best interpretation.

**Recreating your data** *
Please use `dput` in the future*

```
stri_split_lines1('Filename    Compound    Chrom.1.RT  IS  IS_RT

1_04        Amp_d6      2.93075     0   0
1_04        Bup_d4      7.280333    0   0
1_04        Cocaine_d3  5.66195     0   0
1_04        10-monohyd  0           Cocaine_d3  5.66195
1_04        2-hydroxy   0           Bup_d4  0
1_04        6-MAM       3.566433    Amp_d6  0
1_05        Amp_d6      2.94        0   0
1_05        Bup_d4      7.3         0   0
1_05        Cocaine_d3  5.65        0   0
1_05        10-monohyd  0           Cocaine_d3  5.65
1_05        2-hydroxy   0           Bup_d4  0
1_05        6-MAM       3.6         Amp_d6  0') %>% {
    a <- stri_split_regex(., '\\s+', simplify = T)
    cl <- a[1,]
    setNames(as.data.frame(a[c(-1,-2),]),cl)
} -> a_d_f
```

So the goal seemed to me to iterate through the records, and if a record has a value in the `IS` column, match that value to it's position in the `Compound` column, and for that row get the corresponding `Chrom.1.RT` value and place into the `IS_RT` column of the record of initial interest.  But there's a bunch that doesn't make logical sense to me; so here's a starting place:

> 1. Loop through the data frame row-by-row
> 2. assign that row as a data frame to `dv`
> 3. if `dv` column for `IS` is not `0`, find the value that is in that cell in the master data.frame, and then find the value for that row in
>      the ORIGINAL data.frame. Use the max-distance as a way of determining
>      which value to use, since there are multiple possibilities.
> 4. assign that to the cell for `IS_RT`
> 5. return
> 6. bind into one data.frame.

```
rbind.pages(lapply(1:nrow(a_d_f), function(i){
  dv <- a_d_f[i, ]
  if(dv[['IS']] != 0){
    all_match <- grep(dv[['IS']], a_d_f$Compound)
    val_matched <- a_d_f[all_match[[which.max(i - all_match)]], 'Chrom.1.RT']
    dv[['IS_RT']] <- val_matched
    dv
  }else {
    dv
  }
}))


   Filename   Compound Chrom.1.RT         IS    IS_RT
1      1_04     Amp_d6    2.93075          0        0
2      1_04     Bup_d4   7.280333          0        0
3      1_04 Cocaine_d3    5.66195          0        0
4      1_04 10-monohyd          0 Cocaine_d3  5.66195
5      1_04  2-hydroxy          0     Bup_d4 7.280333
6      1_04      6-MAM   3.566433     Amp_d6  2.93075
7      1_05     Amp_d6       2.94          0        0
8      1_05     Bup_d4        7.3          0        0
9      1_05 Cocaine_d3       5.65          0        0
10     1_05 10-monohyd          0 Cocaine_d3  5.66195
11     1_05  2-hydroxy          0     Bup_d4 7.280333
12     1_05      6-MAM        3.6     Amp_d6  2.93075
```

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you for your help! I wasn't sure how to use dput to put my table in here, sorry. On the output you got, Line 10 IS_RT should = Line 9 Chrom.1.RT; basically each filename is a sample that has been tested for a set of compounds, and each sample/Filename value will have different Chrom.1.RT values for the Compounds in it. For line 4, I need it to match the IS value of Cocaine_d3 to the Compound row with that name, then grab the value on that row (row 3) and put it in IS_RT on line 4. For line 10, it would get the Chrom.1.RT value from line 9. Does that help?

Comment: I kind of saw that... made a comment above. So my suggestion is `split (a_d_f, a_d_f [[1]])` and use the same function above, but loop the split list with it. Sorry I'm out now so typing from phone

Answer (score 0):

```
matched_compounds <- merge(
  df1[, c('Filename', 'IS', 'IS_RT')],
  df1[, c('Filename', 'Compound', 'Chrom.1.RT')],
  by.x = c('Filename', 'IS'),
  by.y = c('Filename', 'Compound'),
  all.x = TRUE
)
df1$IS_RT <- matched_compounds$Chrom.1.RT
```

Comment: This one didn't work for me. It just took the values for the IS RT on the first filename and repeated then for the others. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working. It seems a bit clunky but it gave me exactly the output I needed. :

```
# Add IS_RT column
df1$IS_RT<- 0

#Get a list of the unique filename values

SampleList <- unique(df1$Filename)

# Make two tables to use as a references, and loop through the list of     unique filenames

for (i in 1:length(SampleList)) {
  foo <- subset(df1, Filename == SampleList[i])
  Reference <- foo
  foo$IS_RT <- Reference$Chrom.1.RT[ match(foo$IS,Reference$Compound)]
  SampleRows <- which(df1$Filename == SampleList[i])
  df1$IS_RT[SampleRows] <- Reference$Chrom.1.RT[match(foo$IS,Reference$Compound)]
}
```

'